# Der Unterschied zwischen »bis jetzt«, »bisher« und »bislang«

Tags: difference, usage, adverb

> Ich wusste bis jetzt nicht, dass sie ledig ist.
>
> Ich wusste bisher nicht, dass sie ledig ist.
>
> Ich wusste bislang nicht, dass sie ledig ist.

In meinem Internetwörterbuch steht, dass diese Adverbien alle **up to now** bedeuten. Meine Frage ist: Wann und in welchem Zusammenhang verwendet man sie?
Danke!

Comment: Ich wollte " she is single" sagen

Comment: _Single sein_ wäre dann besser. _Ledig sein_ bedeutet nur _unverheiratet sein_, was wenig mit Single-oder-nicht zu tun hat.

Comment: Das sind nur drei  Varianten. Man kann das auch mit "noch nicht" ausdrücken. Das wußte ich noch nicht.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Bisher* und *bislang* würde ich als weitgehend synonym betrachten. *Bislang* klingt ein bisschen altmodischer oder gehobener. Wichtig dabei ist, dass beide nicht nur *bis zu diesem Zeitpunkt* bedeuten können, sondern gegebenenfalls auch *darüber hinaus* einschließen können:

> Ich hab bisher noch niemanden mit einem Messer attackiert. (Und eigentlich auch nicht vor, es zu ändern.)

Im Gegensatz dazu präzisiert *bis jetzt* den Zeitpunkt *jetzt*, insbesondere dadurch, dass er eine Änderung der Situation bewirkt hat, die einschneidend ist.

> »Ich hab bis jetzt noch niemanden mit einem Messer attackiert«, sagte der auf frischer Tat Ertappte der Polizei bei seiner Festnahme.

Etwas anders ausgedrückt: Wenn ich *bisher/bislang* nicht gewusst hab, dass sie einen Freund hat, dann können durchaus Indizien da gewesen sein, die aber alleine nicht ausreichend für Klarheit waren. Wenn ich es *bis jetzt* nicht gewusst habe, dann bin ich entweder bass erstaunt über das, was du mir gerade gesagt hast, oder ich hab sie gerade beim herzlichen Küssen beobachtet und erzähle dir das brühwarm.

Comment: Ist das Wortspiel, dass „mit einem Messer attackieren“ eine „einschneidende Änderung der Situation bewirkt“, beabsichtigt?

Comment: @Loong Nein, das ist mir gar nicht aufgefallen, als ich das geschrieben habe :D

Answer (score 2):

Die Vorkommen sind unterschiedlich hoch (Archiv W DeReKo):

```
bisher     1706353 66,38%
bislang     753428 29,31%
bis jetzt   110713  4,31%
           2570494 100,00%
```

Eine deutliche Präferenz von "bisher" existiert bei Vergleichen mit "als" und "wie" (Prozentangaben beziehen sich auf Gesamtvorkommen des Wortes)

```
bisher      170.218 9,98%
bislang      17.092 2,27%
bis jetzt       502 0,64%
```

Semantisch sehe ich einen subtilen Unterschied darin, dass "bis jetzt" passender ist, wenn man die Betonung auf einen Zeitpunkt anstatt auf einen Zustand legt:

> Ich habe bis jetzt gearbeitet.

"Ich habe *bisher/bislang* gearbeitet" impliziert da etwas anderes, nämlich generelle Berufstätigkeit, *bis jetzt* hingegen konkrete Arbeit in einem überschaubaren Zeitraum.